# "Incomplete type"-error when trying to open ifstream

Tags: c++, input, io, header-files

I am trying to read a file in C++, using the built in compiler of Visual Studio 2019. Following some examples I found, I try this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    ifstream file("test.txt");
    string input = "";
    while (file >> input) {
        std::cout << input;
    }
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
}
```

However, while compiling Visual Studio shows the error `incomplete type is not allowed`. The output window shows `error C2079: 'file' uses undefined class 'std::basic_ifstream<char,std::char_traits<char>>'`.

Following [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50841816/c-ifstream-has-incomplete-type) like so:

```cpp
ifstream file;
file.open("test.txt");
```

gives me the same error.

1. What does the error mean?
2. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include additionally two headers

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
```

Pay attention to that instead of this declaration

```
string input = "";
```

you could just write

```
string input;
```